# CPU overheating even under moderate load, fan/heatsink looks ok and is properly installed

Tags: temperature, overheating, intel-core-i7

CPU: Intel 7th Generation Core i7-7700T BX80677I77700T with stock cooler
Motherboard: Supermicro X11SSZ-QF-O

Bench tested the motherboard, CPU and RAM overnight, and it ran memtest86+ all night without any errors or odd behavior. So I went ahead and completed the installation (installed everything into the case, etc.) However, after installing an OS (Debian 11.6 Bullseye) I am now getting overheating alarms under even mild load. Just the act of booting the system (startup processes, etc.) cause the overheat alarm to peep several times, and running almost any task (e.g. just compiling a simple "hello world" C program) will cause it to turn on solid until the system goes back to completely idle.

Checking lmsensors when the system is idle reveals normal looking temperatures, around 30-35 C, which is pretty consistent to what my other machines are registering. When the overheat warning is on and I check lmsensors I am seeing package temps of ~80 C and individual core temps ranging from 65-80 C.

Let me go ahead and answer what you are probably going to ask next.

- No, I am not overclocking.
- Airflow is good. The only things in the case right now are the motherboard, PSU and two SSDs. All cables are tucked away relatively neatly, and fans are not blocked. And, being a new build, dust build-up, etc. is not an issue, because there is none.
- Yes, the CPU cooler is attached properly. I turned all the knobs clockwise, lined them up with the holes on the motherboard, and pushed until I heard a nice solid "click" and it feels solidly no, no wobble, etc.
- No, there isn't any sort of plastic film or anything else covering either the CPU or the heatsink.
- Yes, I properly applied thermal paste. (when I lift the heatsink, I see the thermal paste spread out in a nice, thin, and even circular pattern indicating that it has correctly spread over the heatsink and die.)
- Yes, I am completely cleaning off and re-applying thermal paste whenever I muck about with the heatsink.
- Yes, all fans are working correctly and are plugged into the correct fan headers on the motherboard.
- Both the system BIOS as well as the IPMI firmware are at the latest available versions.
- I have looked through both the BIOS and IPMI web interface and didn't see anything relevant that I could tweak.

Any ideas as to what's going on, other things I should look into, etc.? I am at my wit's end here...

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like something that I was having a years back. I switched to Windows and the overheat issue goes away. Nope, I'm not a big fan of M$. After a series of trials I discovered the issue might be related to the compatible device drivers that my Ubuntu was using for the chipset.
Sorry for not having any complete data to back it up, been quite a while.
So my suggestion is dual booting to Windows, use Windows for a while and see if the overheating issue also goes away. If so, the option of trying other distro, finding alternate drivers or continue using Windows is yours to take :p